# LessCssProcessor import and declaration for wro4j

Tags: java, maven, less, wro4j

I'm trying to use a LessCss processor in my maven project using wro4j version 1.45. I use this import statement and I get an error at build time saying it isn't recognized.
`import ro.isdc.wro.extensions.processor.support.less.LessCssProcessor;`

All help is appreciated

Comment: The latest wro4j version is 1.7.0. Also, use Less4j processor which is much faster when comparing to LessCssProcessor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The import statement was wrong, here is the correct import statement:
`import ro.isdc.wro.extensions.processor.css.LessCssProcessor;`